# Restrict authenticated website users' access to s3 subfolder

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3

I need to ensure that authenticated users logged into my website only have access to the subfolder assigned to them in an S3 bucket and no other folders.

The scenario: I have a website that allows logged in users to upload videos. On S3, each user has his own folder within a top-level bucket.

When a user logs in, the site loads a page with S3 URLs to their videos. To ensure only authenticated users can view videos, all S3 videos are private. However, there is a bucket policy that allows GET requests if the HTTP referrer is my site so that a user who clicks on a link can view the video.

Under this setup, is it possible for one user to manipulate the HTML in some way or use some other loophole to view the videos of another user?

Is there are better way to ensure that an authenticated website user only has access to a certain subfolder of an s3 bucket? I looked into pre-signed URLs, but the required expiration point seems problematic. As long as the user is logged in, I would like them to have access to their files on s3.

Thanks.

Comment: Note the [**Caution** message in the IAM documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition): *"`aws:referer` should not be used to prevent unauthorized parties from making direct AWS requests. It is offered only to allow customers to protect their digital content, stored in Amazon S3, from being referenced on unauthorized, third-party sites."*  In other words, against simple hotlinking by other *sites* without action by the browser user.  It has essentially zero value for actual security.  What is your application's back-end platform?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, thank you for pointing me to the caution message. I suspected as much. Our back-end stack consists mostly of python, flask, gunicorn, nginx.

Comment: Seems like using [signed cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html) with CloudFront is the best way to restrict access to only authenticated users of my website for my use case. Problem with pre-signed URLs is that my users need to have access to the videos for editing, so I want the expiration length to be long, but don't want too many URLs exposed. Are these cookies more secure than presigned URLs?

Comment: Signed cookies and signed URLs are, at one level, identical in the security they really provide, because they're both providing credentials to the browser.  Signed cookies do offer more of something that might arguably qualify for the label "security" in a practical sense, because the user can't simply right-click+copy+paste = share the links.  They can of course extract the cookies and share them, but in an environment where doing so would expose *the user's own* content, it seems unlikely that this represents a significant problem.  Of course, no matter what, your site needs HTTPS.